# indexpath.row keeps resetting after I introduced sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, sections

I added sections to my UITableview that are generated dynamically. I have a nice little chunk of code that works out which index to place the section headers at. So my `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` code works great.

Problem is my tableview looks like this, say my `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 2, 3, 5:

> -==A==- 
>  Aaron 
>  Alex 
>   -==B==- 
>  Aaron 
>  Alex 
>  Alfred 
>   -==C==- 
>  Aaron 
>  Alex 
>  Alfred 
>  Bart 
>  Casey

So basically every time a new section begins, the `indexPath.row` resets back to 0?

Is there a way around this? Or do I have to tediously maintain which `indexPath.row` is needed for each cell myself?

Right now it looks like I have to loop through my array of names, work out which `indexPath.section` I am in, then go and count how many letters per section and calculate an offset.

Comment: It is normal, row resets for each section. You could modify you data structure to have an array ( for sections ) of arrays ( for the rows ) and return array[section].count for the numberofrowsinsection.

Comment: I want to add: in your assumption index path would be futile. It is especially designed to *do not* found trough the whole array. These protocol methods are designed to work like reality. You say "first row of second section", right? This is how you have to think of it.

Comment: Just a thought more: the short way is indeed to calculate the absolute index, it depends what do you use it for. If you want to mess later with cell heights and dynamic additions/filtering consider the array in array, otherwise the absolute indexing will become a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an `indexPath` contains a row and a section. you can calculate the absolute row by adding the previous sections and its rows:

```
NSInteger absoluteRow = indexPath.row;

for(int section = 0; section < indexPath.section; ++section)
{
    absoluteRow += [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}
```

another (in my opinion better) way is so use an two dimensional array as data structure. the array contains sections and every section contains rows of the section. you can load data by using:

```
[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: I tried the absoluteRow thing, it doesn't work when you scroll for some reason. I think this is because if you have a half section showing then the offset gets muddled up. 

I'm going to bite the bullet and change my fundamental data structures.

Comment: arg of course it doesn't work, sorry. you have to add all previous sections. i updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, that did it. Having to change my data structure would have been a PITA and slow things down a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to tell the rows of each section what to display. An easy way is to have a dictionary with the section names as the keys and the values for these keys as an array containing the specific items for each section.

You probably would need to add some kind of sort function in here using a dictionary approach but if your using names then sorting alphabetically is probably a feature you want anyhow.